# merging all files into one file?

Tags: files, text-processing, join

I was trying to merge all the text files in to one file. All the text files has one column and equal number of rows. 
My data file names are 
data_1.txt, data_2.txt, data_3.txt, . . . data_n.txt. 
where n is the number of text files to be merged. 
I want the merge from 1 to n in their order. 
I tried the following code, but it doesn't work as I wanted. It doesn't keep the column order.

My sample data looks like

data_1.txt

```
0.020085
0.0017361
0.77963
0.98659
0.33102
0.099835
0
0
0.073004
0.29978
```

data_2.txt

```
0.021407
0.0017191
0.82385
1.0449
0.34593
0.10535
0
0
0.078362
0.31509
```

data_3.txt

```
0.022706
0.0016876
0.85447
1.0922
0.35556
0.11063
0
0
0.083983
0.32536
```

required output

combined.txt

```
0.020085    0.021407    0.022706
0.0017361   0.0017191   0.0016876
0.77963 0.82385 0.85447
0.98659 1.0449  1.0922
0.33102 0.34593 0.35556
0.099835    0.10535 0.11063
0   0   0
0   0   0
0.073004    0.078362    0.083983
0.29978 0.31509 0.32536
```

Would you please help me in correcting my problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
paste data_*.txt > combined.txt
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using paste. You'd want `cat *{1..n}.txt >> combined.txt`

Comment: What do you mean by "their order"? Maybe editing your question and adding an example would help.

Comment: Please give some example input and desired output.

Comment: @Gnouc, I added my sample data in my question. Thanks

Comment: @Abraham: How `paste` does not satify your requirement?

Comment: Are you files MS-DOS files with CRLF line endings?

Comment: @Gnouc, It does the merge but couldn't keep the order from 1 to n. It mixes the order of the columns in the output file.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, they are text files. I don't know their endings.

Comment: @Abraham: What is output of `cat -et file.txt`?

Comment: I tried it and still it didn't work. Meachel Homer's solution did what I exactly wanted. Thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`, you can affect the ordering of filename generations with glob qualifiers:

```
paste file_*.txt(n)
```

would turn on *numeric* sorting, that is put `file_10.txt` *after* `file_9.txt`

Note that if your files end in CR characters (as when they come from the Microsoft world), when output to a terminal, that character moves the cursor to the first column.

So for a file containing `A\rB\rC\rn` (as would happen if you `paste`d 3 MS-DOS formatted diles), `cat that-file` would seem to display only `C`. You can get rid of those CR characters by piping the above to `tr -d '\r'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) with `paste` to force an ordering:

```
$ paste data_{1..3}.txt
0.020085    0.021407    0.022706
0.0017361   0.0017191   0.0016876
```

Braces expand to several words, each of which has the parts to the left and right of the braces. The `n..m` syntax is a [sequence expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion):

> A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are either integers or single characters, and incr, an optional increment, is an integer. When integers are supplied, the expression expands to each number between x and y, inclusive.

The above command line will be expanded to:

```
paste data_1.txt data_2.txt data_3.txt
```

which includes the files in the right order. You can change the `3` to whatever the number of files is to get all the appropriate filenames.

The `paste` command joins its file arguments together columnwise in the order they're given as arguments, so the ordering of arguments matters. When you use `*` the filenames are expanded in alphabetical order, which will be wrong when you have 10 or more files, and so the columns will end up out of order then. For 1-9 files you'd be fine either way.

Comment: @Micheal Homer, Thank you very much. It does exactly what I wanted with a brief explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
paste -d " " 1.txt 2.txt > 4.txt
```

There is another way using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s",$1; getline < "1.txt" ; printf " %s\n",$1}' 2.txt
```